What is the worst hot air balloon disaster in history in term of lives lost?
I've been wondering what's the worst hot air balloons disaster in history? I know there are many fatal crashes and accidents in aviation history, but most of them are airliners and other commercial jet aircraft. Hot air balloons had once been one and only way of going up into the sky. So there must've been some crashes and accidents that history just forgot about. Does anyone know a list of hot air balloon disaster ranked in casualties numbers?
Note: I'm looking for hot air balloon disasters, not rigid air ships disasters. I know about the famous Hindenburg disaster and the crashes of the ill-fated US Navy airships USS Akron, USS Macon, USS Shenandoah, and ZR-2 which never made its way back to the US. But I'm looking for actually hot air balloons that crashed with a lot of fatalities.

There's literally a list on Wikipedia...

@Chris why don't you put that link in an answer, copy the row with the Luxor accident. Would be an acceptable answer.

Whoever downvoted my question, please provide a suggestion or improvement in the comments so that I can know how to improve.

@AircraftEnthusiast007, Welcome to Aviation.Stackexchange! I'm not the downvoter, but a guess: it is the expectation here that you do your research before asking questions, and in this case, a google search of "hot air balloon accidents" would have yielded the Wikipedia page that Chris indicated.

There's a list on Wikipedia. The deadliest was in Egypt in 2013, with 19 deaths.
